# It is possible to share a file(PDF) instead of url with navigator.share?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-web-apps

I have a pdf file that is generated from server and I would like to allow the user to share this file via navigator.share. Is it possible to share a file instead of URL?

```
    navigator.share({
          title: 'Web Fundamentals',
          text: 'Check out Web Fundamentals — it rocks!',
          url: 'https://developers.google.com/web',
      })
        .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
        .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome 93.0.4570.0 now supports sharing PDF files with Web Share. See https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/7d30d42a018d4aa76fca2896f2903d892b5f5284 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006055

```js
shareButton.onclick = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://example.com/files/hello.pdf");
  const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

  const pdf = new File([buffer], "hello.pdf", { type: "application/pdf" });
  const files = [pdf];

  // Share PDF file if supported.
  if (navigator.canShare({ files })) await navigator.share({ files });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple explanation, helped me a great deal :)

Answer (score 5):

Chrome for Android (75+) now supports this feature ([called Web Share API Level 2](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4777349178458112#)) and hopefully other browsers will follow suit soon.

A demo is available [here](https://wicg.github.io/web-share/demos/share-files.html).

Comment: As of 03/09/2020, It seems that it is not possible to share PDFs on Chrome https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783254/3670829

Comment: In [this article](https://web.dev/web-share/) I found a link to the list of Permitted File Extensions in Chromium: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tKPkHA5nnJtmh2TgqWmGSREUzXgMUFDL6yMdVZHqUsg/edit#heading=h.6mjoavl6z0mu

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share your pdf file, I will suggest that you provide them as direct links to `url` property. Note that a `url` of '' refers to the current page URL, just as it would in a link. **Any other absolute or relative URL can also be used**.

Comment: Currently the file sharing is not available with Web Share api so I will try to follow you suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, hope this helps. Kindly accept my answer if it successfully implemented. Thanks :)