# Web-share api level 2 PDF support

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, w3c

I am using web-share level 2 for my PWA app. Every media format is working fine except PDF. Web api is returning base64 string of PDF, At client side, I am creating blob object from it. but when I share it, Throws exception : Permission Denied

```
 var file = new File(["/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...."], 'filename.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });

var filesArray = [];

filesArray.push(file);

 navigator['share']({files: filesArray})
        .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
        .catch((error) => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
```

I don't have any clue whats going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It is possible to share a file(PDF) instead of url with navigator.share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825330/it-is-possible-to-share-a-filepdf-instead-of-url-with-navigator-share)

Comment: sharing .pdf files works in Chrome v 93 and latest

Answer (score 3):

For others who might encounter this problem, this was discussed on https://github.com/w3c/web-share/issues/141 and is a current limitation in Chrome tracked in https://crbug.com/1006055